# ASP.NET MVC comparing values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make AddPet form that will transform all the Data from the View (form) into the controller and then in the controller to create the pet with Link commands (In the controller I have the instance of my db)

Full Code:
**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddPet(string Pname, int Page, int Pcategory, string Pimage, string PDescription)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal()
        {
            Name = Pname,
            Age = Page,
            CategoryID = Pcategory,
            PictureName = Pimage,
            Description = PDescription
        };

        _context.Animals.Add(a);
        
        return View("AddPet");
    }
```

**View:**

```
    <div class="mainscreen">
        <div class="petbox">
            <div>
                <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/5vMt4yXH3WJfVGUro74UJ7/159813a78d63638d4a223a78e997f989/compressed_shutterstock_1283470036.jpg?fit=fill&w=800&h=300"/>
            </div> 
            <div class="rightside">
                    <form action="">

                        <h1>Add Net Pet</h1>
                        <h2>Pet Details</h2>
                        <p>Pet Name:</p>
                        <input placeholder="Pet Full Name" type="text" class="inputbox" name="Pname" required />
                        <p>Pet Age: </p>
                        <input placeholder="Pet Age" type="number" class="inputbox" name="Page" required />

                        <p>Pet Category</p>
                        <select class="inputbox" name="Pcategory" id="selectcategory" required>

                            <optgroup label="--Select a Pet Category--">
                                <option value="Mammls">Mammls</option>
                                <option value="Rodents">Rodents</option>
                                <option value="Fish">Fish</option>
                                <option value="Reptiles">Reptiles</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        <div class="picselect">
                            <p>Select Image:</p>
                            <input type="file" name="Pimage" id="file">
                        </div>
                        <p></p>
                        <p>Description Filed:</p>
                        <textarea name="PDescription" class="inputbox" id="desription" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Write here pet descrition"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="button" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddPet">Add Net Pet</button>

                    </form>
               
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model (Animal.cs):**

```
public class Animal
{
    [Key]
    public int AnimalID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PictureName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:**
Error 405:
Debug Console : `"crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."`

Comment: `new Pet { Name = Pname, Category = Pcategory, .... }`?

Comment: I can't do it, it's not belong to the Context DB and there is no instance of my Animal props (Animal.Name, Animal.Age)
I need something like this:
Animal.Name = Pname, 
Animal.Age = Page....

Comment: Is your question "How to create or update an Entity Framework entity from a POSTed model or DTO"?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a class to hold the property values. For example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Discriton{ get; set; }
}
```

This Animal class has to match your entity type object for Entity framework.
Then in the action do:

```
public IActionResult AddPet(string Pname, int Page, string Pcategory, string Pimage, string Pdiscriton)
{
   Animal a = new Animal(){
    Name = pname,
    Age = page,
    Category = Pcategory,
    Image = Pimage,
    Discriton = Pdiscriton
   };
   
   _context.add(a);
}
```

**Update:**
If you change the name of the parameters of the action then you do not have to create and assign the values to the object. You can take advantage of the default model binder like this:

```
public IActionResult AddPet(Animal a)
{
    if(a != null)
        _context.add(a);
}
```

in this case the name of the UI elements has to match the name of the properties of the class. e.g. either `Pname` or `Name` should be used both in the UI and in the Animal class.

Comment: I've a class model with the same properties and that class (model) connected with DB (_context) in my controller (actions)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check. Also can you clarify what you mean by "inside the Controller to make it hold my setting"? What settings?

Comment: Its almost working, I've now
 Action - AddPet (string pname....etc)
Model - Animal.cs (Animal a in controller)
View - AddPet.cshtml with form and same Name as the props
but I can't _context.SaveChanges because it's error me because Description is NULL but it's not even sent me to the View first. without the SaveChanges I am getting to the view and can fill the form , after submit, all the details go inside the AddPet(pname..)
And with [httppost] I am getting error 405.

Comment: @meitaredri 405 is method not allowed. Meaning you are not passing all the parameter from the View to the action properly. You need to share your full code. Otherwise it is not possible for one to guess what you are passing as parameter. It is the rule of the stackoverflow to point out the line where you are having an issue.

Comment: Thank you Rahtur, I've edited the thread and post all my code and explanation there.

Comment: There, You have marked the `Description` as [Required] but not supplying the value. Either remove the [Required] attribute or supply the value for the `Description` field.

Comment: Also what are the filters applied to the AddPet Action?

Comment: I've supply the value for the Description, or I am not really understand your meanning.
Anyway when I press the 'add pet' buttom it's error 505 it's not even take me to the form. I found that it because the HttpPost attribute.

Comment: You said "it's error me because Description is NULL but it's not even sent me to the View first" then 505 error. Not sure which one as we cannot see your full code. You need to tell us exactly in which line the error occurs and what is the error. Does your code hits inside the action?